# I'd like my private virtuals now, please

Tags: c#

What is the reasoning behind disallowing private virtual functions?

Empty private virtuals would have enabled low friction pure customization points.

Abstract functions have high friction and protected virtuals cause confusion and noise.

**Some further explanation:**

The Non Virtual Interface pattern separates the interface responsibility (public) from providing customisation points (virtual).

When using NVI in class design I have to make my virtuals protected.
Having the option to make them private makes the intent even stronger. It means that descendants can *only* provide customisation and there is no confusion over whether to call the base or not, in fact it is prohibited. There must have been a good reason to explicitly disallow it (Diagnostic: "Private method cannot be polymorphic").

Comment: It seems to me that `private` and `virtual` **should** be mutually exclusive. They're a bit at odds with each other in intent.

Comment: how would you use a private virtual method as a "customization point"? private means you can't override it in subclasses because it isn't _visible_ there. So of what use would it be? The big picture is evading my comprehension, it seems...

Comment: Indeed. Private functions are not visible in derived classes. Virtual functions are meant to be used in derived classes. So what is a possible use you'd have for this? Give an example of something you'd like to do, and we can tell you why it would never work (even if it were allowed by the compiler) and what is a better way to do it.

Comment: +1 and vote for reopen. I think this is a good question, even if many of you might find it trivial, for beginners such as me

Comment: @BlackBear aggree on the quality of the question but it is definately not trivial since even the SO luminaries stumble

Comment: The "Some further explanation" added to the question makes me think that what the OP really wants is an interface, not a base class.

Answer (score 9):

A private member means a derived class can't access it.

A virtual member means a derived class can override it.

A class can't override a member if it can't access it.

---

<sup>Discounting nested classes.</sup>

Comment: Haha this reads like a modus ponens example to me.

Comment: A private member *can* be accessed in a nested class, however. Private virtual methods *could* be overridden in a nested class deriving from its containing class. It's a pretty obscure use case though :)

Comment: @JonSkeet: Interesting catch.

Comment: Descendants not being able to access the base implementation is one of the key benefits, i.e. a pure customization point.